# Upload confirmation with Fine Uploader using Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Fine Uploader provides an example [Laravel controller](https://github.com/FineUploader/php-laravel-s3-server/blob/master/ExampleController.php) to upload to S3. The upload can be triggered in FU's config with:

```
signature: {
  endpoint: '/uploader'
},
```

and a corresponding route in Laravel:

```
Route::post('/uploader', 'ExampleController@endpoint');
```

So far so good. To verify the upload to S3, I need to trigger this stanza in the controller:

```
if(isset($this->req->success)){
    //after successful upload
    //the request will contain the bucket and key at this point
    return $this->verifyFileInS3($this->shouldIncludeThumbnail());
} ....
```

The corresponding configuration entry is:

```
uploadSuccess: {
  endpoint: X
},
```

My question is: what is X above? (I have tried X='/uploader?success', X='/uploader?success=true' )

Comment: I can't help with Laravel questions, so I added the Laravel tag. In short, you'll need to create a new route in Laravel and then use the URL of that new route in your `uploadSuccess.endpoint` value.

Comment: Thanks Ray. Perhaps it is actually working. This is what I see:

[Fine Uploader 5.13.0] Received the following response body to an upload success request for id 0: {"invalid":true}
s3.fine-uploader.min.js:2 [Fine Uploader 5.13.0] Upload success was acknowledged by the server.

It seems successful, but I am not sure about the invalid:true thing.

Comment: does not look correct to me. looks instead like the response from your signature endpoint

Comment: You're right: the file was never verified.

Comment: Fine Uploader developer here: I've decided to, for the most part, stop contributing to Stack Overflow after many years of membership. Mostly due to the fact that the creators/organizers refuse to follow their own rules. And partly because it's probably just easier to handle issues and requests all in one place. So, these types of questions can now be posted directly to the Fine Uploader issue tracker at https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues. But please be sure to include a _detailed_ description of your question along with _any_ and _all_ related code.